# "Cannot load module 'metal' as 'Metal'"

Tags: swift, metal, xcode11

I'm following a tutorial - https://www.raywenderlich.com/7475-metal-tutorial-getting-started - to learn how to use metal. I've done exactly what the tutorial said to do and no errors pop up before I try to build it, then it says build failed, along with the error - cannot load module 'metal' as 'Metal'.
I can't find an answer anywhere else, so can someone help me fix this? I'm new to coding and I'm expecting this to have a straightforward solution.

**Edit:** So I just discovered that there was indeed a very simple solution. I hadn't downloaded the materials for the tutorial. But now that I have, another error has shown up, saying `Use of unresolved identifier 'vertexBuffer'`

Here's my entire code, just to resolve any confusion -

**viewControllerer.swift -**

```
import Metal
var device: MTLDevice!
var metalLayer: CAMetalLayer!
var pipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState!
var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue!
var timer: CADisplayLink!


class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
      metalLayer = CAMetalLayer()          // 1
      metalLayer.device = device           // 2
      metalLayer.pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm // 3
      metalLayer.framebufferOnly = true    // 4
      metalLayer.frame = view.layer.frame  // 5
      view.layer.addSublayer(metalLayer)   // 6

    let dataSize = vertexData.count * MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: vertexData[0]) // 1
    vertexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: vertexData, length: dataSize, options: []) // 2

    // 1
    let defaultLibrary = device.makeDefaultLibrary()!
    let fragmentProgram = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "basic_fragment")
    let vertexProgram = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "basic_vertex")

    // 2
    let pipelineStateDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
    pipelineStateDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexProgram
    pipelineStateDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentProgram
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm

    // 3
    pipelineState = try! device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: pipelineStateDescriptor)


    device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
    commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()

    timer = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(gameloop))
    timer.add(to: RunLoop.main, forMode: .default)
  }
  let vertexData: [Float] = [
     0.0,  1.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
     1.0, -1.0, 0.0
  ]

  func render() {
    guard let drawable = metalLayer?.nextDrawable() else { return }
    let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = drawable.texture
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColor(
      red: 0.0,
      green: 104.0/255.0,
      blue: 55.0/255.0,
      alpha: 1.0)

    let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()!
    let renderEncoder = commandBuffer
      .makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor)!
    renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
    renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
    renderEncoder
      .drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 3, instanceCount: 1)
    renderEncoder.endEncoding()
    commandBuffer.present(drawable)
    commandBuffer.commit()
  }

  @objc func gameloop() {
    autoreleasepool {
      self.render()
    }
  }
}
```

**Shaders.metal**

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

vertex float4 basic_vertex(                           // 1
  const device packed_float3* vertex_array [[ buffer(0) ]], // 2
  unsigned int vid [[ vertex_id ]]) {                 // 3
  return float4(vertex_array[vid], 1.0);              // 4
}

fragment half4 basic_fragment() { // 1
  return half4(1.0);              // 2
}
```

**Note -** Shaders.metal is a file that the tutorial says to create

Comment: Check if your project name is not Metal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `Metal` framework as below (mentioned under **Creating an MTLDevice**),

```
import Metal
```

Currently you are doing as below which is wrong,

```
import metal
```

Comment: if i write "import Metal" it just gives me the same error, except now the error shows up in the compiler, not after trying to build

Comment: also how do i get the code to stand out on its own in a comment?

Comment: to put code in line, wrap the text in backticks ` .

Answer (score 1):

The compiler detected a similar name to `Metal`, which is `metal`. Sometimes libraries change name in their own different versions, that's why it can be different from the tutorial you're following.

try doing as the error suggest and replacing the import with: `import metal`

Comment: when i do that it just says - file 'viewController.swift' is part of module 'metal'; ignoring import

Comment: Then just remove the import line

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `var vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer` variable